# Plot above matrix

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, tikz-matrix, nicematrix, bordermatrix

I need Help !

I need to add the yellow dot with arrow. In my model

If possible something like coordinates so that in the future you can move the point from place

[image: matrix bcg]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{231,152,0}

\begin{document}

{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\arrayrulecolor{myorange}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c c l>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}| l>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm} | }[cell-space-limits=\tabcolsep]
 & & \Block[fill=myorange]{1-4}{\color{white}\bfseries long text}\\
 & & \Block[fill=myorange]{1-2}{\color{yellow}text} & & \Block[fill=myorange]{1-2}{\color{yellow}text}&\\
 \Block[fill=myorange]{4-1}{\rotate\color{white}\bfseries long text} & \Block[fill=myorange]{2-1}{\rotate\color{yellow} text} & \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a} & &  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b} & \\
 &  & & \textcolor{myorange}{\large\bfseries text:}\par\footnotesize some text that occupies multiple lines &   & \textcolor{myorange}{\large\bfseries a longer text:}\par\footnotesize some text here some text here\\
 \hline
   & \Block[fill=myorange]{2-1}{\rotate\color{yellow} text} & \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-c} & &  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} & \\
 &  & & some text here &   & some text here\\
 \hline
\end{NiceTabular}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not get me wrong, but what precisely is "minimal" about your example code?

Comment: I am sorry but I can not compile your code. At least `lib/fbunitex2` is missing, Neither Vaca nor Abacaxi.

Comment: Sorry ! Have fixed @SimonDispa

Answer (score 1):

You draw the arrow by using Tikz instructions in the `\CodeAfer` of the `{NiceTabular}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{231,152,0}

\begin{document}

{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\arrayrulecolor{myorange}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c c l>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|l>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|}[cell-space-limits=\tabcolsep]
\CodeBefore
  \rectanglecolor{myorange}{1-3}{2-6}
  \rectanglecolor{myorange}{3-1}{6-2}
\Body
& & \Block{1-4}{\color{white}\bfseries long text}\\
& & \Block{1-2}{\color{yellow}text} & & \Block{1-2}{\color{yellow}text} \\
\Block{4-1}{\rotate\color{white}\bfseries long text} 
& \Block{2-1}{\rotate\color{yellow} text} 
& \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a} & &  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b} \\ 
& & & \textcolor{myorange}{\large\bfseries text:}\par\footnotesize some text that occupies multiple lines & & 
\textcolor{myorange}{\large\bfseries a longer text:}\par\footnotesize some text here some text here \\ \Hline
& \Block{2-1}{\rotate\color{yellow} text} & \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-c} & &  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} \\
& & & some text here &   & some text here\\
\Hline
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [line width=2pt,gray]
  \draw [->] (4-|5) ++(6mm,0) -- ++(-9mm,0) ;
  \draw [fill=yellow!50] (4-|5) ++ (6mm,0) circle (4mm) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{NiceTabular}}

\end{document}
```

`(4-|5)` is the node at the intersection of the (virtual) horizontal rule number 4 and the vertical rule number 5.

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]